# Shell send pipe value as a file input

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to see if it is possible to get an input from a pipe as if it was a file. I have a script (say a python or c++ script) that accepts a file as input. However my file is very big, so usually I'd do `head -50 <file> > small_file.txt` and run my script on `small_file.txt`. I'm looking to see if there's a shortcut to this, such as accepting the input from `head -50 <file>` directly. I tried `< $(head -50 <file>)` but that doesn't work.

Comment: If you can modify the python code, a common convention is that an argument of - indicates to use stdin or stdout as appropriate for that named file argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got close, but the right syntax to use is [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) syntax in `bash`,`zsh` shells of type `< <()` . Something like

```
script.py < <(head -50 file)
```

The idea is when the shell expands the `<(..)` construct, the command inside is run asynchronously and it is made to appear as if it were coming from a file, a named FIFO to be specific.

With the command substitution syntax as shown in the OP, the `< $(..)`, the output of `$(..)` is placed literally for the file input redirection to read from. But it won't work because the file redirection operator assumes that a file name is fed to it but just sees bunch of string input.

Notably there is an alternate variant of process substitution of form `>(..)` which is the opposite of the above variant, used to write to the command run inside the braces. With `<(..)` one is expected to read from the substitution, and the command is set up to use it as stdout. With `>(..)` one is expected to write to the substitution, and the command inside is set up to use it as stdin.

Comment: Just note that this way the program won't be able to perform operations like mmap, seek, tell etc. on the file, and won't be able to tell its size etc. etc.

Comment: @oguzismail: Yes that's true

Comment: Thanks for both of your inputs. This clears things up a lot. I understand why seeks..etc won't work, but I don't think I'll be needing them.